# Get image in MVC and display using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, image

In MVC, We are going to get image from server and display it in client, GetImage Action in controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(int ImageID)
{
    byte[] imgByteArray=GetImageByteArrayFromDB(ImageID);
    string contentType = "Image/jpeg";
     return File(imgByteArray, contentType,  "Image10.jpg");              
}
```

And javascript code in client side is as follows:

```
 $.ajax(
...
  success: function (response) {
                $('#imgResult')
                 .attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response);
           },
    error: function (er) {
                        alert(er);
          }
```

The response is received successfully but image is not displayed and src value is set to:

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,�����JFIF���������C����C        �������&quot;�������������� �������}�!1AQa&quot;q2���#B��R��$3br�
```

How can resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. Which encoding is used in database? utf-8? Or maybe there is some other functionality in `GetImageByteArrayFromDB` function that affects the output of the binary data.

And just to double check, that the image stored in database is actually is valid image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Controller is returning a `File` object to the View and the JS is outputting that data.

You need to convert your bytearray to a base64 string then use that in the view.

e.g.

```
byte[] imgByteArray=GetImageByteArrayFromDB(ImageID);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgByteArray);
return Content(String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", base64));
```

then:

```
$.ajax(
...
  success: function (response) {
                $('#imgResult')
                 .attr('src', response);
           },
    error: function (er) {
                        alert(er);
          }
```